# Why setting a box-shadow does not work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function Change(obj, evt)
 {
    if(evt.type=="focus")
        obj.className ="textboxOnClickStyle";

    else if(evt.type=="blur")
       obj.className ="textboxStyle";
 }
 </script>
```

this is the code for the Textbox

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textboxStyle" onfocus
 ="Change(this, event)" onblur ="Change(this, event)" CausesValidation="True"> 
</asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to make my textbox having glow/shadow by applying another css when the text box is clicked. This code works fine in Firefox but in chrome nothing happens. Can anyone point out why?

**Edit**
CSS code

```
.textboxStyle
 {
border-color: #9ECAED;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;


  }

 .textboxOnClickStyle
 {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;
     box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;

  }
```

Comment: Show the CSS. May we assume you are using non-Mozilla-vendor CSS?

Comment: What is that `event` variable supposed to be? Check your error console, I guess it's not apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [WebKit's Bug Report #45417](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45417) (and [Chromium's downstream one](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54577)). You need to set an *explicit* `border` as a workaround to make it work.

```
.textboxOnClickStyle {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #6DC421;
  border: none;
}
```