# Box-shadow javascript style not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Here is my code
 `[...document.getElementsByTagName("td")][i].style.boxShadow="10px 20px 30px blue";`
It worked on mozilla but not on chrome or edge.
I tried many solutions like `style.["boxShadow"]` also not working.

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543677/9163685

Comment: sounds also simular to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112995/box-shadow-behaviour-on-td-elements

Comment: Thanks BeSter Development. Your link is worked. The problem is `overflow: hidden`  on **td**  tag.